# How does typescript transform each type of a union type just like the map function in a js array

Tags: typescript

I have this type

```js
interface EventDataMap
{
    "aaa": string;
    "bbb": number;
    "ccc": boolean;
}

type t1 =  [ "aaa", "bbb" ]
```

I want to get the following types directly

```js
type resultT = { event_name: "aaa", value: string } | { event_name: "bbb", value: number }
```

This is very much like the map method for arrays，I tried to write the following type, but got an error。

```js
type rt = t1[number] extends infer T ? {event_name: T, data: EventDataMap[T]} : never;
```

I also know how to correctly get the type I want, but I think this way is not good enough, one reason is that it is not general enough, and the other reason is that it is not direct enough, The following implementation I think has a lot of imperfections

```js
interface EventDataMap
{
    "aaa": string;
    "bbb": number;
    "ccc": boolean;
    [p: string]: any; // This statement is necessary, but it seems superfluous
}

type t1 =  [ "aaa", "bbb" ]
// I think UnionToSomeObj is not generic enough, this generic is extracted separately, but in fact its value applies to a single scene, if you can write a generic generic I think it is acceptable
type UnionToSomeObj<T> = T extends string ? {event_name: T, data: EventDataMap[T]} : never;

type t3 = UnionToSomeObj<t1[number]>;
```

The final question I think there are two.

Question 1: How do you get a generic type similar to map function?

Question 2: The type I tried to write `type rt = t1[number] extends infer T ? {event_name: T, data: EventDataMap[T]} : never;` Why doesn't T work?

In fact, I also thought of a special way to write it. Of course, this syntax typescipt is not supported.`type rt = t1[number] as p extends string ? {event_name: p, data: EventDataMap[p]} : never;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the following type

> type resultT = { event_name: "aaa", value: string } | { event_name: "bbb", value: number }

here is the solution:

```
type ResultT = { [K in t1[number]]: { event_name: K; value: EventDataMap[K] } }[t1[number]];
```

For Question2: we need to use **Extract** utility type to ensure that **T** is constrained to only the **keys ("aaa" | "bbb" | "ccc")** that exist in EventDataMap. This allows **T** to be used as an index for **EventDataMap** without resulting in an error.

Solution:

```
    type rt = Extract<t1[number], keyof EventDataMap> extends infer T
  ? T extends keyof EventDataMap
    ? { event_name: T; value: EventDataMap[T] }
    : never
  : never;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Question 1

Here is a way :

```
type Result = {
  [K in t1[number]]: {
    event_name: K,
    data: EventDataMap[K]
  }
}[t1[number]];
```

This might seems a little weird at first, but here is what happen :

We construct an object type containing for each values corresponding to type `t1[number]`, an object type accordingly to what you want.

Then we "return" one value corresponding to `t[number]`, that will be inferred during the implementation.

It is a way to infer the type during implementation.

There are other methods where we would have to explicitly pass in the generic parameter what key we want to use, but i don't think they are the best solutions

```
type Result<T extends t1[number]> = {
  event_name: T,
  data: EventDataMap[T]
};

const result: Result<'aaa'> = {
   // ...
}
```

---

### Question 2

In this situation where T is inferred from `t1[number]`, Typescript cannot know automatically that T can also be of type keyof `EventDataMap`, so you have to extends it

```
t1[number] extends infer T extends keyof EventDataMap ? { event_name: T, data: EventDataMap[T] } : never;
```

### Update following your comment

This will result as this type :

```
type ResultType = { 
  event_name: "aaa" | "bbb";     
  data: string | number; 
}
```

To improve the type (to only allow `string` if `event_name` is 'aaa' etc...), as you said you can do this :

```
type ResultType = (
  t1[number] extends infer T  
    ? T extends keyof EventDataMap 
      ? { 
          event_name: T, 
          data: EventDataMap[T] 
        } 
      : never 
    : never
)
```

And it works perfectly fine !

##### But why ?

It has to do with [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).

In the first case with `t1[number] extends infer T extends keyof EventDataMap`, TypeScript can't infer `T` as a specific key of `EventDataMap` because `T` is dependent on the condition `T extends keyof EventDataMap`. This essentially causes TypeScript to interpret `T` as any key from `EventDataMap` and then combines the result into a single type:

```js
{ 
  event_name: keyof EventDataMap, 
  data: EventDataMap[keyof EventDataMap] 
}
```

In this combined type, `event_name` can be any key from `EventDataMap`, and `data` is the type associated with that key.

However, in the second case with `t1[number] extends infer T  ? T extends keyof EventDataMap ? ...`, TypeScript infers `T` as a specific key of `EventDataMap` because the `extends` check occurs after the `infer` clause. This effectively enables TypeScript to infer `T` as an individual key of `EventDataMap` used inside the type object we're writing.

So here, `T` is ONE specific key from `EventDataMap`, and TypeScript applies the conditional type to each member of the union (`t1[number]`) separately, which preserves the distinct types:

```js
{
    event_name: "aaa";
    data: string;
} | {
    event_name: "bbb";
    data: number;
}
```

In this union type, each variant corresponds to a specific key from `EventDataMap` and its associated type. This behavior is a fundamental aspect of how TypeScript handles distributive conditional types.

Comment: `type ResultType = t1[number] extends infer T extends keyof EventDataMap ? { event_name: T, data: EventDataMap[T] } : never;`
The resulting type is：
`type ResultType = {
    event_name: "aaa" | "bbb";
    data: string | number;
}`
The following writing method can obtain the correct type, which is a strange phenomenon
`type ResultType = t1[number] extends infer T  ? T extends keyof EventDataMap ? { event_name: T, data: EventDataMap[T] } : never : never;`

Comment: Yes you are right, i was missing something. Apparently if infer `T` depends on the condition `T extends keyof EventDataMap`, Typescript won't be able to correctly infer `T` as a specific key of EventDataMap. However, if we do the extends after, inside the infer clause, that will allow TypeScript to infer `T` as one key of EventDataMap used inside the type object we are writting

Comment: （Because if if infer T depends on the condition T extends keyof EventDataMap, Typescript won't be able to correctly infer T as a specific key of EventDataMap, it will be instead used as any key of EventDataMap.）Is there any reference to this statement anywhere in the official typescript literature? If so, can you give me a link to the information?

Comment: After some research i can affirm that this has to do with how typescript handle the distributive conditional types (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) but it is not very clear how it works in this case. I have updated my answer to try to share my understanding of the concept, hope it can provide the information you need

Answer (score 1):

Usually you need to use [distributivity](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) in such cases:

```js
interface EventDataMap {
    "aaa": string;
    "bbb": number;
    "ccc": boolean;
}


type IntoUnion<M, Keys extends keyof M = keyof M> = Keys extends any ? { event: Keys, data: M[Keys] } : never

// type Result = {
//     event: "aaa";
//     data: string;
// } | {
//     event: "bbb";
//     data: number;
// } | {
//     event: "ccc";
//     data: boolean;
// }
type Result = IntoUnion<EventDataMap>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mMO7rw)

In order to make this line work:

```js
type rt = t1[number] extends infer T ? {event_name: T, data: EventDataMap[T]} : never
```

You need to apply extra `extends` to `infer T` to assure TS that T is a keyof EventDataMap:

```js
type rt = t1[number] extends infer T extends keyof EventDataMap ? {event_name: T, data: EventDataMap[T]} : never
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in TS there are three primary methods of mapping:

1. Record mapping

```
type MapEach<K extends PropertyKey> = { [P in K]: Mapped<P> }
```

2. Conditionless distribution

```
type MapEach<K> = K extends K ? Mapped<K> : never
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^ distributes K
```

3. Tuple iteration

```
type MapEach<A extends unknown[]> = A extends [infer F, ...infer L] ? [Mapped<F>, ...MapEach<L>] : []
```

Here is how they can be appiet to your case: https://tsplay.dev/dimava-mapping-v1

```
interface EventDataMap {
  "aaa": string;
  "bbb": number;
  "ccc": boolean;
}

type t1 = ["aaa", "bbb"]
// you may inline it, it's just for simplicity here
type Mapped<T extends keyof EventDataMap> = { event_name: T, data: EventDataMap[T] }

type MapEachR<K extends keyof EventDataMap> = { [P in K]: Mapped<P> }[K]
type MapEachC<K extends keyof EventDataMap> = K extends K ? Mapped<K> : never
// 
type MapEachI<A extends (keyof EventDataMap)[]> =
  | A extends [infer F extends keyof EventDataMap, ...infer L extends (keyof EventDataMap)[]]
  ? [Mapped<F>, ...MapEachI<L>] : []

type R = MapEachR<t1[number]>
//   ^?
// type R = Mapped<"aaa"> | Mapped<"bbb">
type C = MapEachC<t1[number]>
//   ^?
// type C = Mapped<"aaa"> | Mapped<"bbb">
type I = MapEachI<t1>
//   ^?
// type I = [Mapped<"aaa">, Mapped<"bbb">]
```

---

---

As for the second question, you need either

```
type r1 = t1[number] extends infer T extends keyof EventDataMap ? {event_name: T, data: EventDataMap[T]} : never;
type r2 = t1[number] extends infer T ? {event_name: T, data: EventDataMap[T & keyof EventDataMap]} : never;
type r3 = t1[number] extends infer T extends keyof EventDataMap ? {event_name: T, data: EventDataMap[Extract<T, keyof EventDataMap>]} : never;
```

to make sure you don't try to index `EventDataMap` with `T` not extending it's `keyof`, causing `Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'EventDataMap'`